# Как устранить ошибку 403?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, битрикс, веб-сервер, хостинг

Есть выделенный сервер на CentOS 7 на котором хостится муниципальный сайт на битриксе. Проблема в том, что сайт (в основном, по ночам) становится не доступен и судя по логам Nginx выдаёт ошибку 403. "Ложится" он на время от 5 до 50 минут и потом сам "поднимается". Доступ для пользователей к директории с битрексом есть на чтение и запись. htaccess (на сколько я могу судить) стандартный битрексовский. Наименование файлов корректное. Думал, что это может быть из-за бэкапов, но "ложится" сайт по времени рандомно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть?

Comment: 403 - Доступ запрещен. Посмотрите в сторону ограничений временных\нагрузочных.

Comment: Каким образом сервер блокировал доступ на короткое время из-за переизбытка редиректов через rk.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл причину (точнее, помог коллега). Оказалось, всё было в банальном фишинге сайта (использовали rk.php для перенаправления на свои сайты). По этой причине, сервер временно блокировал балансировщик пересылающий эти запросы серверу. Решается это всё в настройках Битрикса. Нужно зайти в интерфейс Битрикса, в раздел меню "Проактивная защита", дальше в "Защита редиректов" и  включить защиту редиректов. Битрикс будет подписывать ссылки через rk.php.

Answer (score 3):

Требуется для начала исследовать кто выдает ошибку 403: Nginx/Apache или PHP-код. Найти это можно в логах nginx/apache и по заголовкам ответа (X-Powered-By).

Далее требуется разбиратся с логами конкретного сервера nginx/apache (и искать в логе ошибок причину ошибки 403) либо при выдаче этого кодом php - разбиратся в нём

Comment: >"Требуется для начала исследовать кто выдает ошибку 403: Nginx/Apache или PHP-код" - 
403 ошибку я обнаружил в access-логах Nginx'а на балансировщике

>"по заголовкам ответа (X-Powered-By)" - 
Тут не совсем понятно. Этот заголовок указывает платформу приложения, в моём случае это PHP/5.6.26. Вы что-то другое ввиду имели?

Просмотрел остальные логи. На самом сервере (его Nginx/Apache), там вроде ничего нет. Как я понял, ошибку с кодом PHP искать там же? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: X-Powered-By - если он есть то 403 выдал php) если нет - то до php не дошло)

Comment: т.е. важно сперва понять - кто выдал ошибку: nginx/apache2/php . nginx или апач  - можно понять по тому в чьих логах она есть а в чьих её нет. если она есть и там и там - то вероятнее всего был ответ от php и потребуется копать туда глубже